# Google Analytics - double refund not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an annoying case.

Let’s say there’s an order with 2 x $5 products.

If I refund one, everything is fine.

I call this code:

```
gtag('event', 'refund', {
  'transaction_id': 'ID',
  'value': "5",
  'currency': 'USD',
  'items': [{
    'id': '01',
    'name': 'PRINGLES',
    'quantity': 1,
    'price': '5',
  }]
});
```

Now, If I call this code again, it is no longer adding up.. so I called this two times, still I see only 1 x $5 refund.

What’s the problem?

I tried calling the function with $10 the second time, but then It showed 3 x $5 refunds.. still no luck

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with import data feature: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014861?hl=en